# The notifications sent from the admin App do not arrive. flutterfirebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

If you can give me a hand. I am working with flutter and firebase with flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0 and firebase_messaging: ^14.3.0.

The notifications sent when the app is installed for the first time on the Android phone that would be the client app are not arriving. But if a notification is sent from that app, after that the notifications start to arrive when it is sent from the admin app.

> main.dart

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // title
        //   'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
        importance: Importance.high,
        playSound: true);
    
    
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    
    Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print('A bg message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');
    }
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
 
 
    
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({super.key});
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;
    
      late TextEditingController _textToken;
      late TextEditingController _textSetToken;
      late TextEditingController _textTitle;
      late TextEditingController _textBody;
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _textToken.dispose();
        _textTitle.dispose();
        _textBody.dispose();
        _textSetToken.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        _textToken = TextEditingController();
        _textSetToken = TextEditingController();
        _textTitle = TextEditingController();
        _textBody = TextEditingController();
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
          RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
          AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
          if (android != null) {
            flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                notification.hashCode,
                notification!.title,
                notification.body,
                NotificationDetails(
                  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                      channel.id, channel.name, // channel.description,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      playSound: true,
                      icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
                ));
          }
        });
      }
    
     
      Future<bool> pushNotificationsSpecificDevice({
        required String token,
        required String title,
        required String body,
      }) async {
        String dataNotifications = '{ "to" : "$token",'
            ' "notification" : {'
            ' "title":"$title",'
            '"body":"$body"'
            ' }'
            ' }';
    
        await http.post(
          Uri.parse(Constants.BASE_URL),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'key= ${Constants.KEY_SERVER}',
          },
          body: dataNotifications,
        );
        return true;
      }
    
      Future<bool> pushNotificationsGroupDevice({
        required String title,
        required String body,
      }) async {
        String dataNotifications = '{'
            '"operation": "create",'
            '"notification_key_name": "appUser-testUser",'
            '"registration_ids":cofigo
            '"notification" : {'
            '"title":"$title",'
            '"body":"$body"'
            ' }'
            ' }';
    
        var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(Constants.BASE_URL),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'key= ${Constants.KEY_SERVER}',
            'project_id': Constants.SENDER_ID
          },
          body: dataNotifications,
        );
    
        print(response.body.toString());
    
        return true;
      }
    
      Future<bool> pushNotificationsAllUsers({
        required String title,
        required String body,
      }) async {
        FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("myTopic1");
    
        String dataNotifications = '{ '
            ' "to" : "/topics/myTopic1" , '
            ' "notification" : {'
            ' "title":"$title" , '
            ' "body":"$body" '
            ' } '
            ' } ';
    
        var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(Constants.BASE_URL),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'key= ${Constants.KEY_SERVER}',
          },
          body: dataNotifications,
        );
        print(response.body.toString());
        return true;
      }
    
      Future<String> token() async {
        return await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken() ?? "";
      }
    
      void showNotification() {
        setState(() {
          _counter++;
        });
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0,
            "Testing $_counter",
            "How you doin ?",
            NotificationDetails(
                android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                    channel.id, channel.name, //channel.description,
                    importance: Importance.high,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    playSound: true,
                    icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher')));
      }
    
      bool check() {
        if (_textTitle.text.isNotEmpty && _textBody.text.isNotEmpty) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
```

The error you perished is already authorized in the AndroidManifest.xml. The problem is only when it is installed for the first time on the phone since when the notification is sent from the client app it works correctly in the foreground, in the background and when the app is closed. I've been looking for the answer for several days and still can't find anything.

I appreciate your help.